# How to access current page URL without using react router or window.location

Tags: reactjs, preact

I've building a lightweight preact widget that gives users different forms based on current url. I don't want to use preact-router as it would affect the routing of the parent website.

So I went with window.location. But the issue, I'm facing is when users navigate internally from one page to another,unless there is refresh, window.location doesn't update the current URL.

Hence if i want to send form 1 to users at /home and form 2 to users at /settings. Users get the same form for both /home and /settings when users navigate internally and only change when they do a refresh.

Can someone suggest me a lightweight solution to fix this? Does in-memory router works for my use-case?

Comment: What do you mean by - **window.location doesn't update the current URL.**

Comment: Hi Harha. Thanks for your response. If a website is using history.push to take users through specific flow ...eg.from /.home..to app.company.com/welcome to app.company.com/upload image. Window.location will give you /home as the current location, unless you refresh the page